# Issue transferring data from ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, ajax

I'm trying to send an associative array of key-value pair from client(javascript) to server(php). The size of the array or the values are not fixed. Need to forward the user selected options from one page to another. Not using forms

Tried using ajax, but php does not receive the array correctly. Using php7, jquery 2.4.1, sql server, javascript

javascript/jquery

```
var contributeArr = {};
$(document).on("change", ".contribute_txt", function() {
    // some other code
    contributeArr[this.id] = this.value;
});

$('#contri_submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var error = false; 
    var contributeArray = JSON.stringify(contributeArr);
    var url = 'chapter.php';            
    var formData = new FormData();
    if (error == false) { 
        formData.append("contributeArray", contributeArray); 
    }
    else { 
        console.log("Something went wrong. Check your code."); 
    }

    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(result) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = url;
            }, 2000);
        },error: function(xhr,request,error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

php

```
foreach ($_POST['contributeArray'] as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION['contribution'][$key] = $value;
}
print_r($_SESSION['contribution']);
print_r($_POST);
```

Sample data from console log:

```
contributeArray, {"LECH":"10","MASC":"20","PMEM":"30","LVME":"50"}
```

Comment: "php does not receive the array correctly"  How exactly are you checking that?  Please provide sample data, the current result, and the expected result.

Comment: and as always... as soon as you're accepting user entered info and passing it to the server... are you validating your data for security?

Comment: Have you used the browser's developer tools to see the request/response of the AJAX?

Comment: Have you made sure that `$_POST['contributeArray']` has been decoded into an array before trying a `foreach`?

Comment: string doesn't work like array do somthing like this, $res=$_POST['contributeArray']; $contributeArray = json_decode($res);

Comment: @PatrickQ 
sample data :
contributeArray: {"MASC":"20","PMEM":"20","LVME":"20"}

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57710469/edit) your question to provide additional relevant information.

Comment: @aequalsb thats not the point and yes Im validating the data and checking other things as well, I have not displayed the entire code but only what you need to see

Comment: have you tried `$('#your_form').serialize()` and passing the entire form serialized to the server... then unserialize it on the server-side?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes, getting 2 different page loads. One with the xhr and the array return from the ajax response and one without. I feel like there may be some issue with my contenttype or something else for php to not accept the response.

Comment: @Rohan i mention because as soon as i have ever answered questions regarding form submission and assuming the OP is validating their data... one of the upper echelon downvotes it and loses their sh*t over it... but it IS a good thing to ask

Comment: Why are you even doing the `JSON.stringify` and `formData` stuff in the first place?  Just pass `contributeArr` directly to the post with `data: contributeArr`

Comment: yeah definitely the issue here is mismatch variable types... can't use `foreach` on `$_POST['contributeArray']` if it is a string...

Comment: set your contentType to `application/json` and just send the serialized `contributeArray` with a root key of `contributeArray` ex: `{contributeArray: {"MASC":"20", ...}}` as your data. You don't need FormData here.

Comment: also... you are setting `url` of the ajax post to 'chapter.php'... is that really really the URL to your AJAX application?

Comment: @PatrickQ I have tried that but having trouble receiving the data on server end

Comment: @aequalsb yes thats the url

Comment: @aequalsb not using form here, so no point serializing anything

Comment: @RohanTapiyawala You still have not described in detail _in what way_ you are having trouble.  You basically just say that it's not working.  That doesn't help us help you.  Please address every part of my very first comment.  Otherwise, I'm afraid we're just going in circles and aren't going to be able to help.

Comment: @PatrickQ trouble is receiving the data on php end. I can see the network tab response with the array, so If there is any error in my code, in fetching or sending the data, I would appreciate any and all help here. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickQ I have updated the question to show the output code for php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note: not sure what `// some other code` is... assuming you have everything correct there for your purposes

and assuming you are validating your $_POST data...

```
var contributeArr = {};
$(document).on("change", ".contribute_txt", function() {
    // some other code
    contributeArr[this.id] = this.value;
});

$('#contri_submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var my_url_value = 'chapter.php';
    var real_url_to_ajax_app = 'https://realdomain.com/realfile.php';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: real_url_to_ajax_app,
        data: contributeArr,
        success: function(result) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = my_url_value;
            }, 2000);
        },error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

in your PHP:

```
// assuming you are initializing $_SESSION['contribution'] per your needs

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // validate key/value here
    $_SESSION['contribution'][$key] = $value;
}

echo 'some helpful response';

exit; // required
```

Comment: Didnt understand the "real_url_to_ajax_app" here. URL to which the response needs to be going is "chapter.php" so what's point of having another url

Comment: @Rohan because the ajax.url must be the full URL to the server-side PHP that will process it... it does NOT simply store some value... it is where the AJAX is posted to

Comment: have you confirmed that you are even receiving the AJAX post at the server? it is one thing to receive data that is not processed correctly... and another altogether to not receive the data at all

Comment: also... the `error` var set by ajax error when posted is the most helpful (imo)... that's why i recoded to error as the first returned var and to console.log that instead... what is the `error` output? this will narrow things down quite a lot...

Comment: Not getting any error. I have already tried your suggested solution, but no response on the server. I receive an object as the response but php is not able to read it. 
tried print_r($_POST); doesnt yield any results.

Comment: I appreciate your help with this question. A bit of a time crunch here, that is why I posted this question here.

Comment: @Rohan if you aren't getting a response on the server... it is very likely you need to set that "ajax URL" (real_url_to_ajax_app in code above) to an actual real URL to a PHP script that will process the request

Comment: @RohanTapiyawala i added a little more to my code to make it more clear what i mean by "real_url_to_ajax_app" to see if this can help you more

Answer (score 0):

Please use json_decode and include latest jQuery.

I can solve your code if you did not solved yet

Comment: Already tried json_decode and latest jquery. All solutions are expected here, not looking for any professional services. Thanks.

Comment: may be there is an other issue but I have tried and modified your code and it was working fine